# set up a Parent son relationship in prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to set up a parent son relationship in prolog such as this

```
James is the father of Fountain Push
```

This is how I got it setup

```
clue5(Solution)  :- parent([_, james], [push , foutain], Solution).
```

in prolog but I keep getting an error ,

```
 clue2/1: Undefined procedure: parent1/3
            However, there are definitions for:
                parent1/2
```

my parent definition is as follows :

```
parent(X, L)
```

Would like to know what I am doing wrong here . thanks .

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please.
And get informed by reading [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: The terminology `foo/n` means predicate `foo` with `n` arguments. So your error is saying that you are querying `parent1` with 3 arguments, but such a definition doesn't exist. The message is being even more helpful by telling you that a predicate definition for `parent1` with 2 arguments exists.

Answer (score 0):

Your `parent(X, L)` predicate only takes 2 variables, `X` and `L`, but you are trying to call it with 3.  You need to either create or update a `parent` predicate to take 3 parameters, or you need to not pass `Solution` into `parent`.

Without seeing the rest of the code, we can't be sure which way is correct.